# Readonly attribute doesn't work on 'o_website_form_date' class in website. - Odoo10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I created a date picker using the following code and set to readonly. The field in the website looks like readonly but when i click on the filed the date picker shows up. i need to disable it too. how can i achieve this?

```
< input type="text" class="form-control o_website_form_input o_website_form_date" name="name" readonly=""/>
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

**EDIT:** When i remove the class `"o_website_form_input"` it works fine.

Comment: set as `readonly='1'`

Comment: @TerrencePoe I tried that, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give 1 to the field readonly.

`< input type="text" class="form-control o_website_form_input o_website_form_date" name="name" readonly="1"/>`